# Need for a new US Visa?

Tags: visas, usa, indian-citizens, passports

I have a expired Indian Passport with a Valid US Visa in perfect condition. Due to some unfortunate event the old US Visa(expired in 2015) on the expired Passport got smudged and now looks a bit faded.
Is the expired Passport now invalid, and so is the Valid US Visa which in perfect condition? 
Do I need to get the Visa re stamped on the new Passport?

Thanks.

Comment: I voted to close, as this question has been asked and answered many times.

Comment: @David, I understand and thought my case was a bit unique. I wanted to be 100% sure and not get sent back at the airlane/immigration. Thank you though.

Comment: No worries. From all the threads on this issue, this situation comes up a lot.

Comment: @David, one follow up question. When I apply for renewal next time in India at US Consulate will they hold the inadvertent damage against me. Since I generally use drop box facility and have heard that they call in for interview if they find some anomaly.

Comment: I'm a US citizen, and have no experience with US visa renewals. If the expired visa is faded but still legible, and you disclose its existence in your renewal application, I'll guess you will have no difficulty.

Comment: Yes all the content is clearly visible. But a bit faded. Thank you.

Comment: I'm confused by your question - you say you have an expired passport with a valid US visa, but then say the expired Visa is smudged.  If you have a valid visa in the passport then the expired one shouldn't matter

Comment: @Midavalo, There are three visas in the expired Passport, of which only one is current and the other two expired. The Visa before the current one got smudged a bit(still legible though). Maybe I am being too paranoid about this thing. :)